# Random tab, auto complete in case of identical file name beginning?

Tags: command-line, bash, autocomplete

Lets say I have multiple files in a directory which all start with the same string

```
$ ls
  fileAA234 fileAA247 fileAA255 fileAA264
  fileAA269 fileAA277 fileAA285 fileAA294
```

Often, when browsing such data files in the command line, I just want to read one, anyone, of these files to see how they are structured.

But if I enter

```
$ less f
```

And then hit tab for completion the answer will be

```
$ less fileAA2
  fileAA234 fileAA247 fileAA255 fileAA264
  fileAA269 fileAA277 fileAA285 fileAA294
```

Which doesn't get me all that much closer to open one of the files.

So for now I either use the mouse to mark a random file name and copy paste it to the prompt, or I lean forward and have my poor eyes figure out a unique string to finish typing the filename.

Is their an easy solution for this? I'm just missing something obvious, right?
I'd really like to have something like <kbd>tab+enter</kbd> to auto complete and open the first file in the list, like in this case `fileAA234`.

Thanks for any help. I imagine there is a way to build a shell script by combining some tools like `ls` and `head` but I'm still a beginner and haven't found a solution myself yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a wildcard (*):

```
$ less fileAAA*
```

That will open the first file in less. When you get to the end of the file, less will continue to the next one. If all you want is a quick look at any one file, and always opening the first (alphanumerically sorted) one is ok, just hit "q" to exit less as soon as you have seen enough.

Comment: Oh boy, i knew there must be an obvious solution. Thanks a lot!
Also works well for directories!

Answer (score 2):

For bash, put the following in `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

This will cause <kbd>Tab</kbd> to always complete full names; press it again to switch between completions

Comment: Thank you, thats really cool. But now, when I enter
    $ cd dir/
and hit tab I won't see the list of subfolders anymore. I have to press enter and use ls.

Comment: @user1323995: Then bind `menu-complete` to a different key instead of Tab. For example, `\C-q` for Ctrl+Q, or `\e[Z` for Shift+Tab.